# Rounding in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor1 IS SELECT STUDENTNAME, COURSEID, COURSEDESCRIPTION, COURSECREDITS, GRADE
    FROM STUDENTINFO
    WHERE STUDENTNAME = '&student'
    GROUP BY (STUDENTNAME, COURSEID, COURSEDESCRIPTION, COURSECREDITS, GRADE)
    ORDER BY COURSEID;
    S_NAME STUDENTINFO.STUDENTNAME%TYPE;
    S_COURSEID STUDENTINFO.COURSEID%TYPE;
    S_COURSEDESCRIPTION STUDENTINFO.COURSEDESCRIPTION%TYPE;
    S_COURSECREDITS STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE;
    S_GRADE STUDENTINFO.GRADE%TYPE;
    S_TOTALCREDITS STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 0;
    S_A STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 4;
    S_B STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 3;
    S_C STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 2;
    S_D STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 1;
    S_F STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 0;
    S_GPABEFOREDIV STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 0;
    S_CREDITSTOGPA STUDENTINFO.COURSECREDITS%TYPE := 0;
    S_GPA NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
    OPEN CURSOR1;
    LOOP 
    FETCH CURSOR1 INTO S_NAME, S_COURSEID, S_COURSEDESCRIPTION, S_COURSECREDITS, S_GRADE;
    EXIT WHEN cursor1%NOTFOUND;
        IF (S_GRADE = 'A') THEN
        S_CREDITSTOGPA := (S_COURSECREDITS * S_A);
        S_GPABEFOREDIV := S_GPABEFOREDIV + S_CREDITSTOGPA;
    ELSIF (S_GRADE = 'B') THEN
        S_CREDITSTOGPA := (S_COURSECREDITS * S_B);
        S_GPABEFOREDIV := S_GPABEFOREDIV + S_CREDITSTOGPA;
    ELSIF (S_GRADE = 'C') THEN
        S_CREDITSTOGPA := (S_COURSECREDITS * S_C);
        S_GPABEFOREDIV := S_GPABEFOREDIV + S_CREDITSTOGPA;
    ELSIF (S_GRADE = 'D') THEN
        S_CREDITSTOGPA := (S_COURSECREDITS * S_D);
        S_GPABEFOREDIV := S_GPABEFOREDIV + S_CREDITSTOGPA;
    ELSE
        S_CREDITSTOGPA := (S_COURSECREDITS * S_F);
        S_GPABEFOREDIV := S_GPABEFOREDIV + S_CREDITSTOGPA;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(S_COURSEID ||' '|| S_COURSEDESCRIPTION ||' '|| S_COURSECREDITS ||' '|| S_GRADE);
    S_TOTALCREDITS := S_TOTALCREDITS + S_COURSECREDITS;
    S_GPA := ROUND((S_GPABEFOREDIV / S_TOTALCREDITS),2);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Credits: ' || S_TOTALCREDITS);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Overall GPA: ' || S_GPA);
    CLOSE CURSOR1;
    END;
    /
```

I need to get S_GPA rounded to 2 decimals. I tried using the ROUND function to 2 spots in multiple spots such as in the

```
Overall GPA: ROUND(S_GPA,2)
```

But I'm still stuck with 0 decimals

Do I have to do this in a select statement somehow? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your actual GPA calculation does not result in an integer? If it does, and you still need the GPA to show two decimals, as in 3.00, then don't simply concatenate S_GPA at the end of your output line; wrap it within `to_char(..., '9.00')`.

Comment: what is the type of `S_GPA`?

Comment: CourseCredits is a number, grade is VARCHAR2

Comment: Why the complicated `open-loop-fetch-exit-end` construction and not the simpler and more efficient [Cursor FOR loop](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm)? And why is it in uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it, I changed S_GPA to S_GPA(4,2).